# PHP : Fetch the image using curl from JSON Format

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to fetch The Image from the JSON format using cURL PHP.
SO I Have created a code through which I am able to fetch the required Image.

The JSON values are in this kind of Format :

```
[
{
"albumId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
"url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
"thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
},
{
"albumId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
"url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
"thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
},
{
"albumId": 1,
"id": 3,
"title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
"url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
"thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
},
]
 ... and so on
```

The php Code I used is Shown Below.

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$albumId = 1;
$id = 3;
$image_data = json_decode($result);
foreach($image_data as $image) {
    if ($image - > id == $id && $image - > albumId == $albumId) {
        echo "<img src=".$image - > url.">";
        echo "<br/>";
        break;
    }
}
```

I am getting the Result that I want but . is this the correct way to implement the code. or are there some loopholes in it. If there, please mention it.

I need the Best Practice available for this Process.

Comment: .. syntax error on line 14 and 15

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by best practice ? because here you don't test anything so it's hard to say anything otherwise that if it's work good for you.

Comment: It works as per my requirements.  @Vindic

Comment: There is no syntax error. the code just shifted on new line. I'll edit that @hanshenrik